# Laravel eloquent get date format from string

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my table, I have enforce column as string (like: '**20170502**').
I want to get the week of the day from this string so I try to convert to date format but that not working.

```
$event = VEventMp::where('event_seq', '=', $mypage_data->event_seq)
    ->select(
        'ENFORCE_PLACE',
        'ENFORCE_FROM',
        \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%y/%m/%d'), '%m月%d日') 
         AS day"),
        \DB::raw('(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(day) = 0 THEN "月"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 1 THEN "火"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 2 THEN "水"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 3 THEN "木"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 4 THEN "金"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 5 THEN "土"
        WHEN WEEKDAY(start_time) = 6 THEN "日" END) AS weekday')
    ->first();
```

Where did I make mistake?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, firstly if the date format is like `20170502` then you must match that in your call to `STR_TO_DATE`, so change that to:

```
STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')
```

Secondly, you can't use an alias in the `SELECT` part of the query so you need to change your `CASE` expression to

```
(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 0 THEN "月"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 1 THEN "火"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 2 THEN "水"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 3 THEN "木"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 4 THEN "金"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 5 THEN "土"
      WHEN WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(ENFORCE_FROM,'%Y%m%d')) = 6 THEN "日" END) AS weekday
```